# Python requests utf-8 post response gets an ascii decode error

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, python-requests, decoding

I send post requests to a RESTful api via python requests and sometimes I get the following error at r.text, r.content andrequests.utils.get_unicode_from_response(r) operations.

I am using python3.

r is:

```
r = requests.post(...)
```

and the error message is:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u015f' in position 133: ordinal not in range(128)
```

(the \ character and position information changes on different requests but the rest of the message is the same.)

I have tried to extract the encoding information of the post response and they all tell me that the encoding is in utf-8 but I cannot decode the response and I cannot understand why the utf-8 encoded bytes get an ascii error (as opposed to a utf-8 error).

Here are the methods that I have tried to figure out the decoding method:

```
>>> r.encoding
>>> utf-8

>>> chardet.detect(r.content)
>>> {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''}

>>> r.headers
>>> {... 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8 ...}
```

How should I decode the messages?

Answer (score 1):

The response is set of utf-8 encoded string bytes which, could contain chars that are not in ASCII table. If it happens you get the mentioned error. So you can either ignore the errors

```
r.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

or handle the response as utf-8 string

Comment: r.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore') is getting the same error:
    'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u015f' in position 96: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

`\u015f` is Unicode.You have to convert it to string

```
("\u045a".encode()).decode("gbk") #using gbk cause question running on windows
```

Change on 9,27,2018.I found it may be a broad question on different platform.particularly on windows.

Comment: r.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore') is getting the same error:
    'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u015f' in position 96: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Selimİmer where you executed the code.It seem to be a broad question. I can output `њ` on my sublime but it doesnt work on cmd

Comment: The code is executed on a darwin python3 environment.
The command works for me too.
However, when I execute it on the responses that I am getting from the server, it returns the ascii encoding error.